# Firebase location best practices for EU application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-compute-engine

Current setup of my application:

BQ: US

Dataflow: US

Cloud storage: US

VM on compute engine for light cronjobs: US

Firebase project: US

Firestore US

most of the website traffic will be coming from Germany/ EU, we currently have page load times around 1s

Some of google beta features are currently not supported in EU.
E.g. cloud functions. Were currently not using them but we might in the near future.

What setup do you think would be best in terms of project location ?

Do you think we'd have a significant advantage to migrate firebase in EU in terms of speed and cost? Firestore DB is generated with regular jobs from BQ exports via python. So I'm afraid I might either migrate everything to EU or nothing...

Comment: Note that (at the time of writing this comment) you have Cloud Functions in Europe (europe-west1), see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations. Also note that Cloud Functions are not in beta anymore.

Comment: this is as of today 26.09.2018 the status of Google Functions https://screencast.com/t/evCpt8xwwQe

Comment: Yes indeed, as shown in the link I refer to in my comment above, there is only one region in Europe at this time: europe-west1. Therefore Cloud Functions are **not** available in europe-west-3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would suggest migration to [Frankfurt am Main](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/frankfurt/); unless you need `TPU`, it's all supported

especially when it comes to web-applications and API - the ping makes a difference;

and this is not only the page-load times, but may be per user interaction (click).

there are also legal implications due to `GDPR`, eg. where the data is being retained ...

see [EU GDPR vs. German Bundesdatenschutzgesetz – Similarities and Differences](https://advisera.com/eugdpracademy/knowledgebase/eu-gdpr-vs-german-bundesdatenschutzgesetz-similarities-and-differences/)